# Display Playlist Thumb (YouTube API)

Tags: api, youtube, thumbnails, playlist

I'm using the YouTube API and there doesn't seem to be a thumbnail image of the playlist as it is on YouTube.

Anybody have any ideas or come across this problem before?

Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the playlist feed, you can access the media:group/media:thumbnail-url tag, which contains urls to each of the thumbnails created by YouTube. You can then use these urls to access the image.

I built a WinFords control to do this... If you need more help, then please ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a thumb link from `http://img.youtube.com/vi/Go1wV4Ikd_I/1.jpg`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing that option Johnny.
I'm usin the .NET assemblies of the api